# Extension of biholomorphic map to the boundary in higher dimension

Tags: several-complex-variables

Well I was thinking on this problem, any idea to progress will be gladly accepted, Let $f:\Omega\rightarrow V$ be a biholomorphic map where $\Omega$ and $V$ are bounded open set in $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $\mathbb{C}^w$ boundary, Does $f$ extend continously to the boundary? for n=1 and not $\mathbb{C}^w$ boundary I have got the answer from thomas here.

Comment: Where is "here"?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153166/extension-of-biholomorphic-map-to-the-boundary

Comment: :) :) :) :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true if $\Omega$ and $V$ are strictly pseudoconvex with $C^\infty$ boundary. It is also true for real-analytic boundaries if the domains are pseudoconvex.

For the non-pseudoconvex case, I need to check some references, but I'm pretty sure the problem has not been solved in full generality. I'm not aware of any counterexamples (for real analytic boundary.)

**Added:** You should check out Fefferman, C.: The Bergman kernel and biholomorphic mappings of pseudoconvex domains. Invent. Math.26, 1-65 (1974)

Comment: Extension for non-pseudo-convex domains (real analytic boundary) in 2 dimensions: http://www.iumj.indiana.edu/IUMJ/fulltext.php?artid=2021&year=1995&volume=44 (Diederich and Pinchuk).

Comment: @LeonidKovalev Thanks for the reference, I had a vague recollection that it was known for $n = 2$.